# New images don't load in Nextjs 13 production mode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-images

I create a full-stack app using Nextjs 13 with the app directory. In dev mode, everything works correctly but in production mode, new images don't load and I get a 404 error in my Chrome DevTools `GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/2023/post-2.jpg 404 (Not Found)`.

I check this URL "http://localhost:3000/uploads/2023/post-2.jpg" and it shows 404, while the file exists at this URL

When I check my upload folder the image exists in my `public => uploads => 2023 => my-uploaded-image`

project directory structure:

src => app

public => assets

public => uploads => year => files

the address of the file I read from the database: `/uploads/[year]/[filename].ext`

example: `/uploads/2023/post.jpg`

`next.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: [
      "localhost",
      "localhost:3000",
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
    "formidable": "^2.1.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.5.0",
    "next": "13.4.1",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.4",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.5.7",
    "tiny-slider-rtl": "^2.9.3"
  }
}
```